# Carrier Furnace Pilot light and Main Burner Flames out when main blower kicks in

Tags: hvac, furnace

Carrier furnace runs for about 3 minutes. Hot air comes out from vent for a minute or so it then turns off and kicks back on after 1 minute or so.

I cannot find the model of the unit as the tag is so old. But here is a picture of the unit.
[image]

Image of inside
[image]

Image of electric pilot
[image]

Wiring Diagram
[image]

Opened up the furnace cover to observe and here is the sequence of the ignition:

1. Thermostat calls for heat.
2. Induction blower turns on. Pilot gas ignites. Last for 1 minute.
3. Main burner ignites. Both Pilot and main burner stays on. Last for 2 minutes.
4. Main blower turns on. Both Pilot light and Main burner turn off immediately.
5. Main blower turns off.
6. Repeat cycle from Step 2.

Video of when both pilot and main burner flames out.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsQV6.jpg

Comment: Perforated heat exchanger? The hot air blower should not be interacting with the flames directly. Do you have a carbon monoxide detector in the house?

Comment: I have a carbon monoxide detector but it did not go off. I have the heater running all night long.

Comment: It could also be a failure of the temperature sensor (probab a thermistor) which signals for the air handler to start the blower motor.* Or it could be the thermistor is signaling correctly but the control board or control circuit is incorrectly reacting. *There could simply be a timer (and no temp sensor) to delay the start up of the blower after the burner comes on, and if so perhaps the timer is malfunctioning. Or the gas valve could be shutting off even though it is getting the signal/power which should be keeping it open.

Comment: Can you post make/model information or the wiring diagram for the furnace, for that matter?

Comment: As @Ecnerwal says I have had that problem and the blower was pushing the air through the heat exchanger which must have rusted through the air would then blow out the pilot.  That problem should be fairly evident just by watching to see if when the blower turns on there is air that blows out the pilot.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel added wiring diagram

Comment: Added a video showing when both flames go out. It looks like they both go out right before the main blower kicks in. Turn on the sound and you can hear when the fan kicks in.

Comment: The main burner really burns 2 minutes before the blower comes on and the flame extinguishes? After seeing the video I was going to guess flame proving fault, but that should lead to the flame-out and blower-on condition within just a few seconds after ignition.

Comment: Yes the main burner burns for a solid two minutes. Then both flame goes out and main blower immediately turns on.

Comment: There is a large spark up near the wiring harness/assembly for the inductor motor right as it flames out. It may be the motor being shut off, but visible sparks from a relay or capacitor seems ... an odd design choice? not normal?

Comment: Those were genuine questions by the way, not sarcasm.

Comment: Good eye. I did not even notice that, I was focusing on the flames.

Comment: @Trani -- do you have a voltmeter/multimeter btw?

Comment: Yes I have a meter

Comment: Called the home warranty and they send a tech he jumped R and W to bypass the thermometer and used a multimeter to check two cables by the fan. He thinks it is the issue with the board and went ahead to replace it. And it did fix the problem.

He thinks the main blower should have kicked on earlier and because it is not blowing it gets overheated and the safety feature cuts off the gas. Thank you everyone for helping.

Comment: @Trani -- post that as an answer and I'll give you a +1 for it, glad it's fixed now!